# TFS command line (team explorer everywhere) and workspaces

Tags: team-foundation-server

I need to be able to check out files with a lock from windows and linux simultaneously.
The only solution I found is using "server workspace".
But, the command line for creating workspaces doesn't have a "location" option:

```
tf workspace -new -login:username,password -server:https://me.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection linux-machine
```

Any ideas what can I do?
Are you aware of any way to create a server workspace from a linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears there is a simpler way to do it the using a `-template`.

There is an undocumented parameter `-location:server` that allows configuring the workspace on the server (without any previous effort).

The command looks like:

```
tf workspace -new -login:username,password -server:https://me.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection -location:server linux-machine
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the server workspace on Windows, then use the `/template` option on Linux to setup the same configuration.